# Getting a 500 error when I try to login to the Magento 2 admin panel

Tags: php, apache, admin, magento2, backend

Currently trying to login to the Magento backend panel (version 2.2.7) but whenever I try to access the admin panel, I'm getting an error reading:

> This page isn’t working www.websitename.com is currently unable to
>   handle this request. 
>   HTTP ERROR 500

I've looked in the logs and there seems to be the following Apache error in them.

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a
>   member function getNext() on null in
>   /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:529\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Locale/Manager.php(96):
>   Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->getInterfaceLocale()\n#1
>   /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Locale/Resolver.php(77):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Locale\Manager->getUserInterfaceLocale()\n#2
>   /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Resolver.php(65):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Locale\Resolver->setLocale(NULL)\n#3
>   /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Locale/Resolver.php(60):
>   Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor),
>   'general/locale/...', 'store', NULL)\n#4
>   /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Abst...\n'

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this as I cannot currently get into the backend of My site.

Comment: [Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on null in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139225/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-create-on-null-in-magento-2)

Comment: Hi. Thanks but that is specific to controllers so not sure how it would resolve the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this was being caused by a vendor extenion called **"Moogento Pickpack"**. Disabling this extension seems to have caused the issue to stop for the moment.

I will get in touch with the extension vendor and try to find out exactly what was causing the problem.

Update:
We have now updated Moogento Pickpack to a new version and upgraded to Magento 2.3.2. The error here is no longer occuring.